# AngularJS: tune ng-model work together with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have following code:

```
<h3>Дата наведвання:</h3>
<select class="form-control" size=info.size()>
    <option ng-model="i.isSelected" ng-repeat="i in info" value="{{i.date}}">{{i.date}}</option>
</select>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="i in info"><p ng-if="i.isSelected">Name: {{i.name}}</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Sorry for dump question. This is simple, I would like my table to show data according to selected date. Please, help me to figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-model` should be there on `select` not on `option` tag. As `ng-model` does only working on `input`,`textarea`,`select` out of the box.

<strike>**Markrup**</strike>

```
<h3>Дата наведвання:</h3>
<select class="form-control" size="info.size()" ng-model="selectedInfo">
    <option ng-repeat="i in info" value="{{i.date}}">{{i.date}}</option>
</select>
```

Where `ng-model="selectedInfo"` will enable two way binding over your select, & selected value would be available inside `selectedInfo` $scope variable.

---

The most preferred way to dealt with select with option by using `ng-options`

```
<h3>Дата наведвання:</h3>
<select class="form-control" size="info.size()" 
   ng-model="selectedInfo"
   ng-options="i as i.date for i in info">
</select>
```

<strike>For showing selected to date you could use `selectedInfo` variable, you don't need to loop over each element of your `info` collection. You could directly do `{{(info | filter: {date: selectedInfo: true })[0].Name}}`(I'd not prefer to go for this approach).</strike>

As you're much interested to take whole element inside `ng-model`, `ng-options` can easily achieve(as I said earlier its preferred). In ng-options case you could do `{{selectedInfo.Name}}`

Comment: also, you should use `ng-options` rather than `ng-repeat` when working with a select box whenever possible.

Comment: @Claies I'm about to add that as well in my answer, thanks for heads up brother, cheers :-)